# Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView, android?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am getting this error on inflating the menu

Logcat:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.createItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:161)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:180)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:170)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:429)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1129)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:91)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:207)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:279)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1021)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1044)
at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:465)
at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:69)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:819)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the menu xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.drawermenu.JavaDrawerActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

This is the java code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.java_drawer, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
    // view
    // boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    // menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Oncreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerLayout = new DrawerLayout(getApplicationContext());
    mDrawerLayout.setLayoutParams(new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mDrawerLayout.setFitsSystemWindows(true);

    content_frame = new FrameLayout(getApplicationContext());
    content_frame.setLayoutParams(new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    content_layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    content_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    content_layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    content_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    tool = new Toolbar(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tool.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tool.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00BBD3"));
    setSupportActionBar(tool);
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (this.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv,
            true)) {
        int actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(
                tv.data, this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        tool.setMinimumHeight(actionBarHeight);
    }
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TOURNAMENTS");




    content_layout1 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

    content_layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    content_layout1.setLayoutParams(new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(320,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.START));
    t = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    t.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    t.setText("XYZ");

    ivBottom = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams par = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
    par.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    ivBottom.setLayoutParams(par);
    ivBottom.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mDrawerList = new ListView(getApplicationContext());
    mDrawerList.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    content_layout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    content_layout.addView(tool);
    content_layout.addView(t);
    content_frame.addView(content_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.addView(content_frame);
    content_layout1.addView(mDrawerList);
    content_layout1.addView(ivBottom);
    mDrawerLayout.addView(content_layout1);

    setContentView(mDrawerLayout);
    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new SideAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            menuTitles, menuIcons));
    // Set the list's click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, tool,
            R.string.action_settings, R.string.action_settings) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

Comment: can you post the toolbar code also

Comment: I am creating the layout through java code

Comment: @Shink I tried your code. Changing app:showAsAction="never" in menu.xml stop application from crashing. However, I am not able to get toolbar as action Bar.

Comment: @Shink Any specific reason for generating tool bar through java code?

Comment: Toolbar is for lollipop support. Since my whole layout is through java code that is the reason for toolbar also

Comment: @Pooja I'm facing same issue. app:showAsAction="never"works and app:showAsAction="ifRoom" crashes. Can you help me on this..?

Comment: I would suggest you to post different question with your issue and log cat. @DharaniKumar

Comment: @Pooja Thanks. nevermind. I solved it. I used "android:actionMenuTextColor" in styles which caused exception & log  similar to this post when adding menu item.